# Moq >= 4.5.7 exposes Exception on It.IsAny<decimal>()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I was using Moq 4.5.3. and decided to update Moq Nuget package to the latest version, which is 4.5.8.
Suddenly, a lot of my tests started to fail. The issue is when using `It.IsAny<decimal>` on optional arguments.
Bellow is a simple, silly test to prove it:

```
public interface IFoo { bool Method(decimal decimalArg = 0m); }

public class Some
{
    public int SomeMethod(IFoo foo) => foo.Method(10m) ? 1 : 0;
}

[TestFixture]
public class SomeTests
{
    [Test]
    public void SampleTest()
    {
        var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
        fooMock.Setup(m => m.Method(It.IsAny<decimal>())).Returns(true);

        var sut = new Some();
        var actual = sut.SomeMethod(fooMock.Object);

        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(1));
    }
}
```

I'm using .Net 4.6.1, nUnit 3.2.1.
The returned exception is: "system.decimal is not a supported constant type".

- Does anyone have an explanation for this issue?
- Is there any fix or workaround?

Comment: Is this really sufficient to reproduce the problem? It sounds like an issue that would be easy to discover before "shipping" a new version. Is the `m.Create` method declared in the obvious way (as in `public IAccount Create(ITransactionalEntity x, decimal y)`) or are there some implicit type casts involved?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Jeppe. I've just found out what's causing this issue.The decimal arg is an optional argument: `IAccount Create(ITransactionalEntity owner, decimal initialBalance = 0m);`. The main issue here is that has been some breaking change in Moq, since this is working on Moq 4.5.3.

Comment: You should edit your question to include this new information. Maybe show the part of `IAccountFactory` introducing `Create`. Are there more than one overload (including possible inherited overloads)?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question. I guess now it has all that's needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: A PR would be even better ;)

Comment: Are all three types `IFoo`, `Some`, and `SomeTests` in the same assembly (project)?

Comment: Yes, jeppe, for the sake of simplicity the code sample is in the same project. The goal is to prove the issue.

Comment: Moq 4.5.7 / MSTest has the same issue. Looks like the introduction of Castle.Core introduced this bug.

Comment: (new Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator()).CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<IFoo>() (see stack trace) gives the same error. Have also a look at [this](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/87) discussion!

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/87) Castle.Core discussion. Removing the default value will solve the problems in this specific test but probably not in all your tests.